# php var_dump($object) or print_r($object) to a log file

Tags: php, magento

This question is generic, and I would simply like to know how to dump objects to log files. In order to clarify things, i am elaborating through an example.

I have been successfully using magento observers to call methods when certain events happen.
As an example, I am observing for when a shipment is saved via :

```
<sales_order_shipment_save_after>
```

and i'm successfully calling a method. I would like to grab the shipment and simply dump the object to a log file. eg.

```
public function newShipment(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
    $shipId = $shipment->getId();
    Mage::log("shipment ({$shipId}) created/saved", null, 'shipments.log');
    //trying to dump $shipment data into the log file
    Mage::log("({var_dump($shipment)}) ------", null, 'shipments.log');
    Mage::log("----------------------------", null, 'shipments.log');
}
```

The shipment id is printed into the log file just fine, but obviously it does not dump the object the way i want it to as the code I have written is wrong.

Can anyone tell me how I could dump an object to a log file and perhaps give me some advice on logging in general?

thanks very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are in Developer Mode you can try if the object supports debug output via `$object->debug()`.

- http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/create-your-own-log-files-with-magelog/

Comment: great! thanks very much that worked perfectly : $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
     Mage::log(var_export($shipment->debug(), TRUE), null,'shipments.log');

Answer (score 28):

```
Mage::log(
    $object->debug(), //Objects extending Varien_Object can use this
    Zend_Log::DEBUG,  //Log level
    'my.log',         //Log file name; if blank, will use config value (system.log by default)
    true              //force logging regardless of config setting
);
```

Answer (score 23):

To be able to use `Mage::log()`, some conditions need to be met:

- developer mode must be set to `true`
- logging must be activated in the system configuration.

But, you can also *force* logging by passing `true` as 4th param to `Mage::log()`.

If all conditions are met (or logging is forced), you should find your log file in `var/log/shipping.log`.

As a side note: Magento objects tend to be *huge* and usually contain tons of informations that you usually don't really need for logging/debugging purposes.

You can reduce the amount of dumped information by using the `getData()` method, a member of all Magento objects extending `Varien_Object`:

```
Mage::log(print_r($shipment->getData(), true), null, 'shipment.log', true);
```

You can also dump single attributes by using its proper getter method:

```
Mage::log((string) $shipment->getId(), null, 'shipment.log', true);
```

If you really need *full* object dumps, I'd recommend to use the `debug()` method of the object to log the data (this method autodetects recursions which helps avoiding endless loops eating up all memory):

```
Mage::log($shipment->debug(), null, 'shipment.log', true);
```

If you can't get `Mage::log()` to work, you alternatively could use PHP's core `error_log` function to log. That's what I sometimes do, if I need just a quick log.

```
error_log(print_r($shipment->getData(), true), 3, 'shipment.log');
```

Comment: great. this is amazing info. im kinda new to SO and im not sure what the etiquette. you provided the most comprehensive and useful answer yet another user helped me actually dump the object to a log file first. i have already marked that as the answer. sorry for the silly question but im not sure what is and whats not done in the community. anyway, thanks very much for this answer!

Comment: Glad it helped^^. The etiquette says, it's completely up to you how many answers you personally want to upvote and which answer you want to accept.

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps you'd use [var_export](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)() function instead, like this:

```
var_export($shipment, 1); // to return the string without sending it to STDOUT
```

Also global functions cannot be called directly within double-quoted string. In your case,
`Mage::log(var_export($shipment, 1) . '------', null, 'shipments.log')` would be ok, I guess. )

If the object you're trying to dump contains circular references, var_export() will fail, though. Then you can either use var_dump + ob_start/ob_flush combo (there are several examples at the [var_dump() doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php)), or take an alternate route with [serialize()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) function.

Comment: Just a note that the var_export called within the Mage::log call should also take 1 as an argument.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have tried your answer and i get the following error instead of the expected result :

Comment: Fatal error: Nesting level too deep - recursive dependency? in ..\Shipment\Model\Observer.php on line 20

Comment: Updated the answer to show the possible remedies in this case.

Comment: thanks for your help and for the advice on the circular references. unfortunately I still have not managed to dump an object to a log file. i will keep trying and if i get it right with your help, ill mark it as correct. thanks again