# How to log a Magento Array?

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to print an array to a log file in magento however it is getting hung up on submitting order information....

```
Mage::log($arr, null, 'logfile.log');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Serialize it to a string in a format you need

Comment: Already tried passing `print_r($arr, true)` as 1st param to `Mage::log()`? Or `Zend_Debug::dump($arr)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385048/php-var-dumpobject-or-print-robject-to-a-log-file

Answer (score 1):

Try to use var_export

```
Mage::log(var_export($arr, true), null, 'logfile.log');
```

Comment: same thing. it just says submitting order info then shows the button again without submitting it. when i comment out the line it submits the order.

Comment: @user2570937. Check your browser console (F12 in FF). Check the response there, too. May be you will see some error.

Answer (score 0):

Following print the entire array in to MyArray.log

```
 Mage::log("Query Order: ".print_r($order->debug(), true),null,'MyArray.log');
```

MyArray.log can be found in

```
  var/log/MyArray.log
```